If $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n}\to N\left(0,1\right)$ in Distribution, then moments converge to moments of normal
Is the method of moments an if an only if statement when the limiting distribution is the standard normal and the moments of the sequence are all finite?

That is, suppose we have a sequence $X_n$ converging to the standard normal $Z$ in distribution and each moment $E_{n}\left(X_{n}^{r}\right)$ is bounded, for each $n,r$, does it follow that the sequence of moments $E_{n}\left(X_{n}^{r}\right)$ converge to the moments of the standard normal?


Yes. Boundedness of $EX_n^{2k}$ for each $k$ implies that $(X_n^{j})$ is uniformly integrable for each $j$ and this  sequence converges in distribution to $X^{j}$. This implies that  $EX_n^{j}\to EX^{j}$.
[ $X_n \to X$ in distribution and $(X_n)$ uniformly integrable implies that $EX_n \to X$].
